# Why does using the "%s" format specifier to printf an array of char output additional nonsense values after the final char in the array?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, format-specifiers

I stumbled upon this behavior that I am curious to understand.

I mistakenly wrote the following at the end of a program to print the elements in an array of `char` :

```
printf("output: %s",outputText[]);
```

when I should have (and ultimately did) iterate over the array and printed each element like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < textLength; i++){

        printf("%c",outputText[i]);
    }
```

What prompted me to implement the latter was the output I was getting. Despite initializing the array to limit the characters to `outputText[textLength]`, ensuring that there were no unexpected elements in the array, my output when implementing the former code would always be littered with additional spooky elements, like below:

[image: spooky character additions]

I've just run the same program three times in a row and got three random characters appended to the end of my array.

(Edit to replace `outputText[]` --> `outputText` in first example.)

Comment: Are you missing the null character?

Comment: `printf("output: %s",outputText[]);` is a syntax error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%s` is for strings; a string is a array of chars ending with NUL (0x00 in hex, or `'\0'` as character), so the `printf()` will print until it finds a NUL!

If you set the last element of the array to NUL, `printf` will finish there.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the `'\0'` character as the element of the character array that marks the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing string terminating character `\0` end of the string. So,  make your string is `\0` terminated. Like:

```
outputText[textLength-1] = '\0';
```